# Facing error when creating a new ionic project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Hi can someone please help me? Upon installing IONIC into my cmd, **I cannot seem to create a IONIC project**.

```
C:\Users\TP_baseline>npm install -g ionic
+ Ionic@0.0.1
updated 1 package in 3.367s

C:\Users\TP_baseline>ionic start myApp tabs
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:716
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\TP_baseline\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic'
[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:15)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:618:27)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:931:10)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11[39m {
  code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: `Ionic@0.0.1` doesn't look like the correct version.. What do you get when you call  `ionic -v`?

Comment: Hi thank you for the effort I managed to solve the issue. The problem sourcing from my NPM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To those whom might face the same error...

It's not something wrong with my IONIC but actually my npm.

The code below helped me to solve the issue:
**`npm cache clean --force`**

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, I found that by creating my IONIC project into a new folder helps! But first remember to install IONIC into that particular folder.

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore to install IONIC into an existing angular project... the line should be "npm i @ionic/angular" instead of npm i ionic.

Hope it helps! https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic/angular